# FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setup org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout while sign in with Selenium ChromeDriver and Chrome

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, testng, selenium-chromedriver

could anyone please tell me , why i get timeout out issue intermittently while sign in on web page after browsing the URL . i get it intermittently , it works fine after i close all the web browser and run the program . the below error message , i want to know the root cause , can anyone help me please !

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setup
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
System info: host: '01HW596115', ip: '10.29.124.26', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Comment: can you share the @BeforeTest script with us

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setup
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
System info: host: '01HW596115', ip: '10.29.124.26', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.42*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.42*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.42/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v68-70**

- You are using *chrome=71.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.45*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v70-72**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.42* and the *Chrome Browser v71.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.45**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version between ***Chrome v70-72*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.